# Lost the Debug Console in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

For some reason, I have lost the Debug Console in Visual Studio 2019. Before, when I was debugging, I was able to see the value of variables when I placed a break in my code, however, today I'm not able to do this. I can't see any changes within the debugger. I have posted a picture of my screen for Visual Studio below.

[image: Visual Studio Screen with no Debug Console]

Comment: the images are identical, and you use Visual Studio, not VS Code

Comment: Thank you, RioV8. I edited the question.

Comment: What happens when you navigate to Debug -> Windows -> Watch (choose one of 4 watch windows) or Debug -> Windows -> Immediate ?

Comment: I think you're looking for the Locals Window: Debug -> Windows -> Locals.

Comment: Thank you so much, Tryer and Pierre!  I was able to find what I was looking for by following Pierre's steps to open Locals Window.